# Any way to force app out of memory in Android emulator?

Tags: android, lifecycle

I've implemented application state saving/loading in onSave/RestoreInstanceState and onCreate in one of my android app's activities.  Is there any way to force the emulator to remove my app from memory so that onRestoreInstanceState is called?

Currently it looks like my app just stays in memory (for a time longer than I am willing to wait anyway).  When I hit the "home" button when my activity is active I get the following method calls:

- onSaveInstanceState
- onStop

When I reactivate my app, all I get is

- onRestart

Is there any way in the emulator to force my app to be mothballed so that onRestoreInstanceState and/or onCreate are called again?

Comment: Not really. But if you open a bunch of other applications, it should eventually push yours out of memory.

Comment: Yeah, that was my fallback.  Seems a bit tedious however.

Comment: You could try testing it on a HTC Desire.  My one seems to only ever have about 50k of storage available.

Comment: If your Activity isn't set to a fixed orientation or handling rotation manually, hit Ctrl+F12 to rotate the emulator.  This will cause a configuration change, which is all you need to truly test state save/restore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [DevTools](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-devtools.html) app ("Immediately destroy activities").

Comment: On newer Android versions (most likely 4.0+) the option is now part of "Developer options" ("Don't keep activities") in the regular Settings app (within the System section).

Comment: Since there is more than one Developer Tools app on Google Play, I'll mention that the one from PandaDev (no connection to me) offered "Immediately destroy activities," and it worked for me on my Nexus One running Gingerbread.  On my Nexus 7, though, checking that option consistently crashed the app, but thanks to the above comment I see I won't be needing the app on that device.

Comment: On Android 4.2, the "Developer Options" section is [hidden by default but can be revealed following a special step](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#42-dev-options).